Direct3D 11 and 2D : wrong display of a texture
I am still trying to improve my test program about Direct3D 11 in 2D, without any additional library (see direct3d 11 and 2D: pass coordinates of a vertex as int and not float).
I now want to display a memory buffer (BGRA colorspace, B being the lower byte) in a rectangle.
The result should be

Note that the pixel at the 4 corners is pink.
When I create the texture and use a shader to draw it in a rectangle of the window, I get:

that is 3 bands (blue, red and pink). I've searched a lot, modify some parameters, without luck.
the code to create the memory buffer and the texture:


unsigned int *data_new(int w, int h)
{
    unsigned int *d;
    unsigned int *iter;
    int i;
    int j;

    DBG_FCT;

    d = malloc(w * h * sizeof(unsigned int));
    if (!d)
        return NULL;

    iter = d;
    for (j = 0; j < h; j++)
    {
        if (j < h/2)
        {
            /* red, otherwise green */
            for (i = 0; i < w; i++, iter++)
                *iter = (i < w/2) ? 0xffff0000 : 0xff00ff00;
        }
        else
        {
            /* blue, otherwise yellow */
            for (i = 0; i < w; i++, iter++)
                *iter = (i < w/2) ? 0xff0000ff : 0xffffff00;
        }
    }

    /* pink on corners, coords (i,j) --> i*h+j */
    d[0] = 0xffff00ff;
    d[w -1] = 0xffff00ff;
    d[w * (h - 1)] = 0xffff00ff;
    d[w * h - 1] = 0xffff7f00;

    return d;
}

/*** texture ***/

Object *texture_new(D3d *d3d,
                    int x, int y,
                    int w, int h,
                    unsigned int *img)
{
    Vertex vertices[4];
    unsigned int indices[6];
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc_buffer;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc_tex;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data_sr;
    Object *o;
    HRESULT res;

    DBG_FCT;

    o = (Object *)calloc(1, sizeof(Object));
    if (!o)
        return NULL;

    /** vertex and index buffers **/

    /* vertex upper left */
    vertices[0].x = x;
    vertices[0].y = y;
    vertices[0].r = 0;
    vertices[0].g = 0;
    vertices[0].b = 0;
    vertices[0].a = 0;
    vertices[0].u = 0.0f;
    vertices[0].v = 0.0f;
    /* vertex upper right*/
    vertices[1].x = x + w;
    vertices[1].y = y;
    vertices[1].r = 0;
    vertices[1].g = 0;
    vertices[1].b = 0;
    vertices[1].a = 0;
    vertices[0].u = 1.0f;
    vertices[0].v = 0.0f;
    /* vertex bottom right*/
    vertices[2].x = x + w;
    vertices[2].y = y + h;
    vertices[2].r = 0;
    vertices[2].g = 0;
    vertices[2].b = 0;
    vertices[2].a = 0;
    vertices[0].u = 1.0f;
    vertices[0].v = 1.0f;
    /* vertex bottom left*/
    vertices[3].x = x;
    vertices[3].y = y + h;
    vertices[3].r = 0;
    vertices[3].g = 0;
    vertices[3].b = 0;
    vertices[3].a = 0;
    vertices[0].u = 0.0f;
    vertices[0].v = 1.0f;

    /* triangle upper left */
    indices[0] = 0;
    indices[1] = 1;
    indices[2] = 3;
    /* triangle bottom right */
    indices[3] = 1;
    indices[4] = 2;
    indices[5] = 3;

    o->stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    o->offset = 0U;
    o->index_count = 6U;

    desc_buffer.ByteWidth = sizeof(vertices);
    desc_buffer.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    desc_buffer.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    desc_buffer.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    desc_buffer.MiscFlags = 0U;
    desc_buffer.StructureByteStride = 0U;

    data_sr.pSysMem = vertices;
    data_sr.SysMemPitch = 0U;
    data_sr.SysMemSlicePitch = 0U;

    res =ID3D11Device_CreateBuffer(d3d->d3d_device,
                                   &desc_buffer,
                                   &data_sr,
                                   &o->vertex_buffer);
    if (FAILED(res))
    {
        free(o);
        return NULL;
    }

    DBG_NAME(ID3D11Device, o->vertex_buffer, "Vertex buffer");

    desc_buffer.ByteWidth = sizeof(indices);
    desc_buffer.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    desc_buffer.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    desc_buffer.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    desc_buffer.MiscFlags = 0U;
    desc_buffer.StructureByteStride = 0U;

    data_sr.pSysMem = indices;
    data_sr.SysMemPitch = 0U;
    data_sr.SysMemSlicePitch = 0U;

    res =ID3D11Device_CreateBuffer(d3d->d3d_device,
                                   &desc_buffer,
                                   &data_sr,
                                   &o->index_buffer);
    if (FAILED(res))
    {
        ID3D11Buffer_Release(o->vertex_buffer);
        free(o);
        return NULL;
    }

    DBG_NAME(ID3D11Device, o->index_buffer, "Index buffer");

    /** texture 2D **/

    desc_tex.Width = w;
    desc_tex.Height = h;
    desc_tex.MipLevels = 1;
    desc_tex.ArraySize = 1;
    desc_tex.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    desc_tex.SampleDesc.Count = 1U;
    desc_tex.SampleDesc.Quality = 0U;
    desc_tex.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    desc_tex.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    desc_tex.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    desc_tex.MiscFlags = 0U;

    data_sr.pSysMem = img;
    data_sr.SysMemPitch = 4U * (unsigned int)w;
    data_sr.SysMemSlicePitch = 0U; /* for 3D resources only */

    res = ID3D11Device_CreateTexture2D(d3d->d3d_device,
                                       &desc_tex,
                                       &data_sr,
                                       &o->texture);
    if (FAILED(res))
    {
        ID3D11Buffer_Release(o->index_buffer);
        ID3D11Buffer_Release(o->vertex_buffer);
        free(o);
        return NULL;
    }

    DBG_NAME(ID3D11Device, o->texture, "Texture object");

    res = ID3D11Device_CreateShaderResourceView(d3d->d3d_device,
                                                (ID3D11Resource *)o->texture,
                                                NULL,
                                                &o->texture_view);
    if (FAILED(res))
    {
        ID3D11Texture2D_Release(o->texture);
        ID3D11Buffer_Release(o->index_buffer);
        ID3D11Buffer_Release(o->vertex_buffer);
        free(o);
        return NULL;
    }

    DBG_NAME(ID3D11Device, o->texture_view, "Texture view object");

    o->type = OBJECT_TYPE_TEXTURE;

    return o;
}

and the shader:
cbuffer cv_viewport : register(b0)
{
    row_major int2x3 rotation_matrix;
    float2 ivps;
}

struct vs_input
{
    uint2 position : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float2 uv : UV;
};

struct ps_input
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float2 uv : UV;
};

ps_input main_vs(vs_input input )
{
    ps_input output;
    float2 o = float2(mul(rotation_matrix, int3(input.position, 1))) * ivps;
    o *= 2.0f;
    o -= 1.0f;
    o.y *= -1.0f;
    output.position = float4(o, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    output.color = input.color;
    output.uv = input.uv;
    return output;
}

Texture2D texture_ : register(t0);
SamplerState sampler_ : register(s0);

float4 main_ps(ps_input input) : SV_TARGET
{
    //return input.color;
    return texture_.Sample(sampler_, input.uv);
}

the complete source code is in this  git repository (d3d_7.c and shader_7.hlsl only for the texture code).
I use dynamic texture because the texture can be changed during the final program execution.
Does someone see where the issue is ?
thank you

Your repo link doesn't work

@SimonMourier the git repo was private. try again

@TomHuntington I don't want to use d2d, just d3d11.

If you are not rescaling you should just use ID3D11DeviceContext::CopySubresourceRegion. To debug you could try hard coding the colors for each vertex in the pixel shader. Ilke a if else for each vertex.

Also the best way to learn is to git clone the official samples and hack on them, without having to do all the boilerplate yourself

@TomHuntington the rectangle can be move, resized, the content could be changed any time. I also write this way to understand what I am doing. I'm sure that I am missing something, but neither the debug infra of d3d11, not the debugger of VS or Renderdoc helped me for now.

Learning to use the debugging infra can be tricky. When I'm stuck it helps to keep trying something simpler until you eventually get something that works. git is your friend. Try a pixel shader without the sampler, try without a index buffer.

Stupid copy paste error. The index of the u and v fields are all 0. Now it works...
